# MVC ajax testing form submission

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I am trying to submit a form using ajax and want to check to see if the
correct values are sent.  How do I do it using the following.  Currently, it is sending it to a MVC controller, but I do not want to do that.  Is there a way to just sent to the same view page and show all the values???

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(sendValues);
});

function sendValues() {
    var a = store.data.items;
    var array = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < store.data.items.length; i++) {
        array[i] = store.data.items[i].data;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].value == "Using") {
            array[i].value = true;
        }
        else {
            array[i].value = false;
        }
    }
    var ClintJSON =
    {
        "Exempt": Ext.getCmp("mmrComboBox").isIndexSelected(2),
        "MM1": Ext.getCmp("mmrComboBox").isIndexSelected(3),
        "MM2": Ext.getCmp("mmrComboBox").isIndexSelected(4),
        "MM3": Ext.getCmp("mmrComboBox").isIndexSelected(5),
        "B1": Ext.getCmp("BComboBox").isIndexSelected(2),
        "B2": Ext.getCmp("BComboBox").isIndexSelected(3),
        "B3": Ext.getCmp("BComboBox").isIndexSelected(4)                    

    };

    $.ajax({
        jsonp: null,
        jsonpCallback: null,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Site/Test")',
        data: "{clinsite: " + Ext.util.JSON.encode(ClintJSON) + ", List: " +      `    
         Ext.util.JSON.encode(array) + "}",
        dataType: 'json'
        , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                showMessage('Site requirements have been updated successfully');
                store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 52} });
            } else {
                showMessage('Site requirements have NOT been updated!!! ');
                store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 50} });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one tool that I cannot recommend enough in this type of scenario, Fiddler2.

You can download it [here](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

It enabled you to examine exactly what is passed to and from the server and you can view the data in various formats i.e. json, web form data or plain old text.

You can also use Composer to simulate http requests, which has its obvious benefits.

As a profession web applications developer, I use this tool all day every day, like I said I can't recommend it enough!!

Cheers

Baz

Answer (score 0):

you can inspect the values in firefox using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console or in chrome tools, just press `f12` and a window will open infront of your

moreover you can log the `ClientJaon` to the console liek

```
console.log(ClintJSON );
```

Comment: how do you use console.log(ClintJSON) in chrome(f12)?  do you include this line in the javascript code like the following:

     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnSubmit").click(sendValues);
     console.log(ClintJSON );
     });

or do you type it into the F12 Console Screen?  
> console.log(ClintJSON )

Comment: You write console.log in your javascript code and this is output to the console screen in F12